# $f$ is a monomorphism $\Rightarrow$ $f$ is injective, alternative proof

Tags: abstract-algebra, category-theory

Reading Aluffi (again) I stumbled across the proof of Prop. **2.3**, which is

$f$ is injective $\Leftrightarrow$ $f$ is a monomorphism in the category **Set**.

This proposition comes in the text after the (Prop. **2.1**) which states

(1) $f$ has a left-inverse $\Leftrightarrow$ $f$ is injective.

Now in the proof of "$\Leftarrow$" in Prop. **2.3** in the book, he says he will use "microscopic" information by going down to the level of sets and elements looking at maps $\alpha', \alpha''$ which only act on sets $Z$ which are singletons $\{p\}$. Then it becomes quickly clear that $f$ only can be an injective function.

Now I wonder if (and if not, why not) one really needs to go back at sets at this stage, or if its not rather possible to proof this using Prop. **2.1**, which would be more elegant in my eyes.

So my attempt is the following:

$f$ is a monomorphism by supposition, proof by contradiction: Assume $f$ is not injective. By Prop. **2.3** that means   $\neg(\exists g: g \circ f = \mathrm{id}_A)=(\forall g: g \circ f \ne \mathrm{id}_A).$ Now it is left to show that $f\circ\alpha'=f\circ\alpha''\Rightarrow\alpha' = \alpha''$ is impossible under that circumstance. And here I am hanging a bit. I am not sure if this conclusion can be made without recurring to mapping elements. Any comment is appreciated!

---

The definition of *monomorphism* from Aluffi this question is referring to is the following:

A function $f:A\to B$ is a *monomorphism* (or *monic*) if the following holds:

*for all sets Z and functions* $\alpha', \alpha'': Z\to A$

$f\circ\alpha'=f\circ\alpha''\Rightarrow\alpha' = \alpha''.$

Comment: A monomorphism in which category...?

Comment: Maybe you could give an answer which depends on the category? Actually in the book its before categories are introduced.

Comment: Moreover, I suppose **Set** would make sense.

Comment: Let $f$ be a monomorphism. We want to show $f$ is injective. Suppose not. We want some contradiction. You can invoke Prop. 2.1, so that $f$ has no left inverse, and to come to a contradiction. You would have to find an explicit left inverse. This might be annoying as $f$ can be anything. So perhaps you can derive a contradiction *directly* by assuming that $f$ is not injective... But saying that $f$ is not injective is a statement on the 'microscopic' level of sets, so it's a pretty natural way to approach the question.

Comment: @R_Berger You need to be more careful. Aluffi does *not* state that $f$ has a left-inverse iff it is injective. Even if he had, there are categories that have monomorphisms that are not split, i.e. do not have left inverses. Therefore you'll need to use some fact about $\mathbf{Set}$ specifically.

Comment: @DerekElkins: 2.1 in my post is a verbatim quote from Aluffi, and as well *nothing* about categories appears up to this point in the book. Not even the term was mentioned, (except in the foreword).

Comment: @R_Berger It's verbatim from the book but it does not include all the *context*.

Comment: @DerekElkins OK, but I think combining your and at_Jeroen s statement I'll start getting what its about, thank you both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Injectivity* makes sense only in the category $\mathcal Set$ of sets and functions.

Then we can extend it to categories $\def\m{\mathcal} \m C$ equipped with an 'underlying set' functor $\m C\to\m Set$, and we will find that most of the times, an arrow in such a ('*concrete*') category is *monomorphism* iff it is injective. 
The other property (having a left inverse) is usually much stronger: the set theoretic left inverses are rarely homomorphisms. 
In $\m Set$ these properties happen to be equivalent.

Comment: In particular, it is sufficient for the "underlying set" or "forgetful" functor to be faithful (which implies if $U(f)$ is a monomorphism, then $f$ is a monomorphism) and representable (which allows proving the converse).  In "algebraic" categories, the representing object for the underlying set functor is typically "the free object on one generator" (e.g. $\mathbb{Z}$ for $Groups$ or $Ab$, $\mathbb{Z}[t]$ for $Rings$ or $CommRings$, etc.)